# How to trim last two characters of each element in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

Here I am getting an array of width values. As it contains `px` in the end of each element. I need to trim `px` and store it in the array.

**HTML**

```
<table id="mytable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:40px;display:none;">Head1</th>
      <th style="width:50px">Head2</th>
      <th style="width:60px">Head3</th>
      <th style="width:70px">Head4</th>
      <th style="width:80px">Head5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:40px;display:none;">1</td>
      <td style="width:50px">2</td>
      <td style="width:60px">3</td>
      <td style="width:70px">4</td>
      <td style="width:80px">5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Jquery**

```
var listWidth = $("#mytable tr th").map(function() {
  if($(this).is(":visible")){
    return this.style.width;
  }
}).get();
for (var i = 0; i < listWidth.length; i++) {
  listWidth[i].slice(0, -1);
}
console.log(listWidth);
```

I've tried using `slice` but, no result.

[**Demo fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/mrgxzvx5/)

Comment: Actually there is a result, but you're ignoring it.

Comment: If the format is always like '30px', you can use parseInt(string, 10); Else yeah, map the array and slice out the last two characters.

Comment: I know everyone will suggest you the best way but for your understanding you are not saving the result of slice so `listWidth[i]=listWidth[i].slice(0, -1);` should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. **To get Inline `width`**

   > I want the inline styled CSS width

   ```
   var listWidth = $("#mytable tr th:visible").map(function () {
       return parseInt(this.style.width, 10);
   }).get();
   ```

   [**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/gpcfnnua/)
2. **To get computed width**

   Use [`width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/). `width()` will give you the numeric width without `px`.

   ```
   var listWidth = $("#mytable tr th:visible").map(function () {
       return $(this).width();
   }).get();
   ```

   [**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vfnoooye/)
3. **To get inline `width` if present else get computed width**

   ```
   var listWidth = $("#mytable tr th:visible").map(function () {
       return parseInt(this.style.width, 10) || $(this).width();
   }).get();
   ```

   [**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/osrtgb3L/)

Comment: will not work in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/uvjgvghs/) case

Comment: @Hazard If you check the `console` of the demo you've given, it'll show `[47, 53, 59, 65]`. So, `width()` gives you correct value even if it is not set.

Comment: I want the inline styled css width

Comment: @Hazard [`return +($(this).attr('style').match(/width:\s*(\d+)/i) || [])[1] || $(this).width();`](https://jsfiddle.net/osrtgb3L/)

Comment: This answer is unnecessary highly complicated in this use case.

Comment: @user1533609 Yes, using `this.style.width` with `parseInt`. Please check update.

Comment: Actually my whole point is using `|| $(this).width()` is completely unnecessary in this use case

Comment: @user1533609 Right. I was keeping it for cases when there is no inline `width` style. As OP is having inline `width` to all `th`, it is not required.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/pn9pr0zz/

```
var listWidth = $("#mytable tr th").map(function() {
if($(this).is(":visible")){
  return $(this).css("width").slice(0,-2); // get width using .css() and use .slice() over here to remove px from string 
  }
}).get();
console.log(listWidth);
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is just to skip `px` in your array you can use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function:

```
var listWidth = $("#mytable tr th").map(function() {
  if($(this).is(":visible")){
    return parseInt(this.style.width, 10);
  }
}).get();
console.log(listWidth);
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mrgxzvx5/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var listWidth = $("#mytable tr th").map(function() {
if($(this).is(":visible")){
  return this.style.width;
  }
}).get();
var arr = []
for (var i = 0; i <= listWidth.length ; i++ ) {
        if ( listWidth[i] === undefined ) {
            break;
    }
        var lWidth = listWidth[i].replace(/px/, "");
    arr.push(lWidth);
}
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var listWidth = $("#mytable tr th").map(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
            return this.style.width;
        }
    }).get();
    for (var i = 0; i < listWidth.length; i++) {
        listWidth[i] = listWidth[i].slice(0, -2); //PAY ATTENTION HERE
    }
    console.log(listWidth);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="width:40px;display:none;">Head1</th>
        <th style="width:50px">Head2</th>
        <th style="width:60px">Head3</th>
        <th style="width:70px">Head4</th>
        <th style="width:80px">Head5</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="width:40px;display:none;">1</td>
        <td style="width:50px">2</td>
        <td style="width:60px">3</td>
        <td style="width:70px">4</td>
        <td style="width:80px">5</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```